# Как заменить бесконечность на вещественное значение?

Tags: c#

Первый вопрос: если взять корень из бесконечности то будет бесконечность?
Если какое то большое число возводится в квадрат, то получаем бесконечность и корень из этой бесконечности даст бесконечность, а не первоначальное число?

Если некоторые значения массива x[i] равны бесконечности, то как сделать так чтобы эти значения вместо бесконечности приравнивались например 100?

Comment: Преобразования при математических операциях в компьютере из-за его особенностей не всегда обратимы =) Там же число представляется в конечном числе бит. И как только их не хватит - тут же результат исказится, и исходное число уже будет не получить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) при вызове `Math.Sqrt(double)` с значением `double.PositiveInfinity`, возвращаемое значение также будет равно `double.PositiveInfinity`.

Аналогичное поведение для вещественных чисел имеет функция [возведения в степень](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.pow.aspx) при значении степени > 0. Там же приведена таблица с различными вариантами бесконечностей (в т.ч. отрицательных) на входе и результирующими значениями.

Для "устранения бесконечности" достаточно пройтись по массиву с проверкой на конечность (обычное сравнение тут не сработает, необходимы вызовы `double.IsInfinity()`, etc):

```
double[] x;

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(x[i])) // или просто double.IsInfinity(x[i])
        x[i] = 100;                      // для включения в т.ч. -бесконечности
}
```